# How do I make an event handler execute two different actions?

Tags: xpages

I have an event handler for an onChange event in a field.  I am trying to get it to display a Dojo dialog if the key provided in the field matches an existing document, but have it create and save a new document with no user input if the key has not already been used.

This is the code for the event handler:

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
refreshMode="norefresh" disableValidators="true"
onComplete="XSP.openDialog('#{id:dialog1}')">
<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var bundleID = getComponent("inputBundleID").getValue();
    if (bundleID == "") {
        return;
    } else {
        var noteID = @DbLookup(@DbName(),"AllBundlesID",bundleID,"$12");
        if (@IsError(noteID)) {
            viewScope.put("noteId","NEW");
        } else {
            viewScope.put("noteId",noteID);
        }
    };
    document1.save();}]]></xp:this.action>

<xp:this.script><![CDATA[var bundleFieldId = '#{javascript:getClientId("inputBundleID")}';
    var bundleId = document.getElementById(bundleFieldId).value;
    if (bundleId == "") {
        return false;
    }
    var trayFieldId = '#{javascript:getClientId("inputStorageTrayID")}';
    var trayId = document.getElementById(trayFieldId).value;
    if (trayId == "") {
        alert('Storage Tray ID cannot be blank');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }]]></xp:this.script>
```

I tried removing the onComplete parameter and adding this below the this.action portion:

```
<xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[[#{javascript:if (viewScope.get("noteId") != "NEW") {
        return XSP.openDialog('#{id:dialog1}');
    } else {
        alert('Create and save the document - TBD how to do it');
    }}]]></xp:this.onComplete>
```

That code gives me the error [ReferenceError] 'XSP' not found.

The alert is just a placeholder until I determine how to create the document automatically.  I feel like I am missing something simple.  Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: As an alternative you can use SSJS to display the dialog: getComponent("dialog1").show();

Answer (score 3):

view.postScript() is a better way of doing it. This is SSJS that takes as its parameter a string that can be parsed as CSJS. So:

```
@If(@IsError(noteID)) {
  view.postScript("alert('Create and save new doc');");
} else {
  view.postScript("XSP.openDialog('#{id:dialog1}');");
}
```

If XSP.openDialog is it working, check you have the Extension Library installed on the server. If you have, that code should work.

Comment: Thanks, @Paul. I neglected to mention that I found the part about using xp:this.onComplete on your blog. :) I had to play around with the partial refresh to get it working at all, but now I get an error when it (I think) tries to run the XSP.openDialog: An error occurred while updating some of the page: dlg is undefined. I can't find 'dlg' anywhere in my code so that makes me think it is in the IBM code. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I only recently came across view.postScript too! May be worth using the in-built Designer search to see if dlg is anywhere in the NSF. Missing "var" out of code doesn't necessarily throw compile-time errors but can throw runtime errors

Answer (score 1):

onComplete fail because it's written as SSJS (#{javascript:/* server side code */}). alert and XSP are client side.

Comment: Thanks, Tommy.  I discovered that later.

Answer (score 0):

Your description says you're trying to display a "Dojo" dialog but your code is calling XSP.openDialog, which opens an ExtLib dialog.  Did you use the ExtLib dialog control?

If it's a Dojo dialog you need to call it with **dijit.byId("#{id:dialog1}").show()**

I think you're kind of on the right path for your other issue but maybe try this:

- Create a panel with a scriptBlock that creates a csjs var from a viewScope (ex. viewScope.keyExist)
- onchange SSJS checks to see if key exists and sets viewScope var.  If it does not exist call create your new doc.  Partial refresh above panel.
- onComplete of partial refresh check var created in scriptBlock and based on that value display the dialog.

Comment: In that case you should be able to incorporate Per Henrik's suggestion and do everything in the SSJS onchange.